# How to override PasswordSignInAsync to add a TenantId in finding user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to add a TenantId filter when signing in Users in PasswordSignInAsync because our UserName is only unique per tenant. How can I achieve this or any other options?

Comment: How the User table is created? Does it mean we have a a foreign key in User table?

Comment: There's UserName and TenantId for Unique constraint

Comment: How do you get the current TenantId ?

Comment: Isn't it easier to combine the two in UserName? Like UserName = "tenant1,username".

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `PasswordSignInAsync` method you should fetch user and after that check `tenantId`. I suppose you have such method:

```
public bool SingInUser(string userName, string password, int tenantId)
{
    var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    if(user == null)
        return false;

    if(user.TenantId != tenantId)
        return false;

    var signInResult = signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: But PasswordSignInAsync takes a UserName string instead of a user object. This line will no compile: 

var signInResult = signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);

Comment: OK, I didn't mention I was using v2.2.0

Comment: It's for Identity 3.

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you need to find a user by his name you'll need to associate it with the `tenantId`, the best practice is to create a custom user store let name it `CustomUserStore` that derives from `UserStore<ApplicationUser>` and override the `FindByNameAsync` method.

So the new class `CustomUserStore` will look like this:

```
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserStore()
    {
    }

    public CustomUserStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        // here you need to get the tenantId
        var tenantId = ...

        return GetUserAggregateAsync(u => u.TenantId == tenantId && u.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

When instantiating your `ApplicationUserManager` instance you need to use CustomStore like below:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

Because many method in ASP.Net Identiy need to execute `FindByUserNameAsync` internally so by using **Mohsen Esmailpour** solution you'll end up creating a custom method for every ASP.Net Identiy method that involve knowing which user we have and the tenantId associated to it. Creating a custom store avoid that kind of thing which is unmaintainable code.